# How to delete multiple rows from Oracle big table?

Tags: oracle11g, delete-row, multiple-records

We have a big table about 380 million records. We need to delete first 250 million records which are older than January 1st 2013. I have googled some methods but I didn't satisfied. Common and fastest way looks like this:

```
create table newbig_table unrecoverable as
select * from oldhuge_table
where <condition is reverse of delete condition>
```

Finally rename the new table to original name but what will be new records inserted continuously?

Main problem is; this table is an **online** table and using by many agents. So I need to delete by not slowing down the system and also not to effect new records. I tried this method by myself:

```
using (SqlConnection connData = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx;User ID=xxx;password=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx"))
            {
                connData.Open();
                int cnt = 0;
                long total = 0;
                long startID = 1039142601;
                long endID = 1385795368;
                long recCount = endID  - startID;
                cnt++;
                long delRange = 400; //deletes 400 by 400

                for (long i = 1; i < endID; i++)
                {                        
                    startTime = DateTime.Now;

                    string deleteSql = "delete from DivaSessionFlowLog  " +
                                    " where ID >= " + startID.ToString() +
                                    " and ID <= " + (startID + delRange).ToString();

                    int strID = (int)((new SqlCommand(deleteSql, connData)).ExecuteNonQuery());
                    total = total + strID;
                    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ":" + strID.ToString() + " OK DelCnt:" + total.ToString() + " ID:" + startID.ToString() + " Rest:" + String.Format("{0:#,#}", (recCount - total)) + " Time:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss"));

                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    startID = startID + delRange;
                    i = startID;
                }
```

In order not to slow down the system program sleeps for 200 miliseconds. However, I calculated the finishing time about **2 weeks**. In conclusion, I need to find;

- fast
- doesn't slows down the database
- doesn't affects the new inserted records continuously

way to delete multiple rows from a big table. Any Suggestions?

Comment: have u tried normal delete with rownum?

Comment: no I didn't. is it faster than standard deleting?

Comment: what is standard deleting?

Comment: if u face this same criteria better create partition table on data!and delete specific partition.it is much easier!!!!do  u need that solution?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would to have the table partitioned, so that older partitions can just be dropped.

However if you need to modify the table, and don't forget that the table might have privileges, indexes, triggers, etc along with it, and you need to keep it available through the process, then you need to use DBMS_Redefinition.

Also, UNRECOVERABLE is old syntax, but you wouldn't want the modern equivalent because if you had a media failure on the system you would have lost the table and the data.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning the table by date would help a lot here. The contents of a particular partition can be dropped far more quickly than deleting rows one by one.

Take a look at http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/partitioning-an-existing-table.php ; this describes how to move from a non-partitioned table to a partitioned one.

Answer (score 0):

Change `delRange` from 400 to 40000 or 400000.

By my calculations, your process will spend 5.015 days in `Thread.Sleep(200)`.  And there is extra time for the network, writing to the console, etc.  Modifying data in chunks is not always avoidable, but you should at least try to use larger chunks.

As others have mentioned, partitioning could very helpful.  But there are a lot of downsides to partitioning, and if this is a rare process it might be worth it to just do it the simple way.